# What is the minimum size a category/group should have for unbiased predictions? skewed distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, categorical-data, predictive-models, skewness

I am trying to find out if there is a correlation between a specific category and age. For example:

> if being a vegetarian has any relationship with age.

The purpose is to use this information to make predictions about age on a test data.

So far it looks like a null-hypothesis question and my first attempt is to apply one of the test statistic formulas in [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_statistic). As the standard deviation of the dataset and size of each category can be calculated I am inclined to `one-sample z-test` .

The thing is I am not sure if the z-test can be applied to skewed distributions. The distribution is given below. **Can z-test be applied to it? If yes do I need any modifications on the formula? If no, why?**

[image: age count graph]

This dataset consists of ~10000 rows. The mean (age) is 32, the median is 30 and the mode is at 26.

What I do is to calculate *the mean age for each category*, compare it with the dataset's mean and decide if the category should be taken into consideration or not while estimating the age. Empirically, if the average age of a category is within 5% of the dataset's mean I ignore that category. I don't have much scientific proof for choosing 5%. **Do you think it is valid?**

During calculations I noticed that sample size for some categories can be quite low compared to 10000. Assuming there was a category of "meaterian" with 35 members and mean age 23, this category would be a gem for predictions (as the local mean deviates greatly from the dataset's) only if the sample size was not too low to be trustworthy. If I get it right, for normal distributions, categories with size of 30+ can be taken into consideration. But in this case, the distribution is skewed and it looks like threshold of 30 cannot be applied anymore.

**So, for skewed distributions, what is the appropriate method to find out the minimum size a category should have so that it can be taken into account while making predictions?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The z- and t-test have convergence properties that can make up for some deviations from normality when sample sizes are large. I question if the mean should be the value of interest when distributions are funky, however, and you’re right to wonder how big of a sample size is necessary for the convergence theorems to kick in.

More important, though, is that z-testing seems inappropriate for your task. It sounds like you have age bins (not ideal to bin ages, but if you don’t have the original ages, you must work with what is available) and a binary variable of vegetarian/not. This sounds like a good place to use a chi-squared test or a G-test. They’re almost the same, and chi-squared is the more mainstream method, though G has an elegance that I like. A more sophisticated approach might treat the age bins as ordinal.

Comment: The last time I checked the chi-squared test I did not understand much what was going on. Considering k (degrees of freedom), should I take it as 1 (due to column "diet") or should I take k as number of unique values in column diet (because every categorical value can be considered as a distint "binary" column)? Or should I take the total number of columns in  the dataset except age?